# Php - Validations and errors - unique name

Tags: php

I don't want to save duplicate name record. I want to display errors back to the user. 
But it doesn't work. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

```
protected function has_unique_name($value, $current_id="0") {

        $sql = "SELECT * FROM photographs ";
        $sql .= "WHERE caption='" . self::$database->escape_string($this->caption) . "' ";
        $sql .= "AND id != '" . self::$database->escape_string($current_id) . "'";
        echo $sql;
        $result = self::$database->query($sql);

        $products_count = $result->num_rows;
        echo $products_count . "<br />" ;

        $result->free();

        return $products_count === 0;
  }

protected function validate() {
        $this->errors = [];

        $value = $this->caption;
        $current_id = isset($this->id) ? $this->id : '0';
            if(!$this->has_unique_name($this->caption, $current_id)) {
              $errors[] = "The name must be unique.";
            }

        return $this->errors;

    }

public function create() {

        $this->validate();
        if(!empty($this->errors)) { return false; }
        ...
```

Comment: `$errors[]` != `$this->errors`

Comment: I don't believe, such a stupid mistake, I've looked at it 100 times and I didn't see it:)